# Opening Methods in Android Studio

Tags: android

Is there a way for me to see what certain methods of built in Android classes look like? For example, If I create a TextView object called output. I can then use one of TextView's methods, for example setText, to display a text within the widget.

```
output.setText("Hello");
```

Is there a way to find the .setText method to manipulate or simply see how it works? There are a ton of built in methods that perform functions and I would like to take a closer look at how they were written. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold CTRL (CMD for Mac) and click on the method you want to see the definition of. This will also work for user defined methods.

If you CTRL click on a variable it will take you to the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

### Goto Declaration

Goes to the declaration of the class, method or variable. Mostly useful on classes and methods since it redirects to the implementation.
`cmd+b` for Mac And `ctrl+b` for other .
For more information [Android Studio Shortcuts You Need the Most](http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-shortcuts-you-need-the-most/)
and [Android Studio Tips & Tricks](http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-tricks-moving-around/)

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio you can use the Key Stroke ctrl + b (cmd + b for mac). This will take you to the source of the method.

You won't be able to modify the code, but you can at least see how it works.

Comment: It can also be done with just "cmd + clicking on the method". But yes, this answer is it.